# Enable event tracing in EF Core

Tags: c#, logging, entity-framework-core, sqlclient

I'm using Entity Framework Core in my ASP.NET Core 6 application and it's having an issue launching when installed as a Windows service. The executable when published works when I launch it from the command line, but fails to launch when installed as a service.

I tried to configure it to run under all different types of accounts such as `SYSTEM`, `NETWORK`, and even my Windows AD account - but without any success. Every attempt is met with this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): The system cannot find the file specified.

In an attempt to see how far along it's getting in `DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection` I need to enable Event tracing for the [SqlClient the code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/enable-eventsource-tracing?view=sql-server-ver16) to pick up the [tracing events available](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/5794ab3af5b58e66b2829a1355b692a73210ee9c/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionPool.cs#L1166C30-L1166C30).

The issue is that that example has a manual creation of a `SqlClientListener` class and using it when performing data access to capture the traces. Is there anyway of doing something similar for EF Core since EF Core uses `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` internally?

The built in [message categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging#message-categories) available via configuration only seem specific enough to EF Core and not the `SqlClient` internals it calls.

Comment: First of all I would try to look into using [EF Core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3) with level set to `TRACE` (you can even use [simple console logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging)).

Comment: As for tracing - you don't need to enable anything as far as I understand you just need to have something to [listen to them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/diagnostic-listeners). As far as I understand you should look into using some kind of tool like [`dotnet-trace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-trace), some profiler or PerfView. But still I would start with just logging.

Comment: I am trying `dotnet-trace` however it doesn't seem to like the provider I supply and defaults to the providers in the default profile. `dotnet-trace collect -- My.exe --providers Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.EventSource`

Comment: Have you tried logging first?

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET Core includes logging by default but it does not include a way to log the underlying Microsoft.Data.SqlClient used by EFCore. There are only EFCore specific [categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging#message-categories).

Comment: Just to be sure: I assume you did what the exception message says? It seems that only named pipes is enabled.